# Problem install wx-tools and the dependencies Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dependencies, wxpython

I am trying to run a software in python 2.7.13 and receive an error "no module named wx".

So I am trying to install wxPython, and wx related dependencies.

I installed wxgtk2.8

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-wxgtk2.8 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

this link (https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_and_configuring_under_Ubuntu) says that I need to install libwxgtk2.8-dev, as well, but this is problematic because it depends on wx-common.  I am not able to install wx-common

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwxgtk2.8-dev : Depends: wx-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the error when install wx-common:

```
 sudo aptitude install wx-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial{ab} wx-common{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,127 kB of archives. After unpacking 3,582 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wx-common : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 is installed.
 libwxbase3.1-0-unofficial : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.42buntu1~14.04.4 is installed.
```

This seems like a tricky circle and I'm not sure how to build wx-common for the goal of install wxPython.  I would like build wxPython as root user, so that the virtualEnvironment can be created with wx module.  After some reading online, it is very difficult to install wxPython in a virtualEnvironment.   hence I am requesting some assistance installing as root.

thank you very much.

if I try to install wxPython I observe:

```
checking elsewhere... no
checking for SM... yes
checking for OpenGL headers... not found
checking for GL/gl.h... no
configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available
Error running configure 
ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
```

Here is my system:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Where are these `unofficial` packages coming from? do you have any wxwindows related PPAs enabled?

Comment: I am not sure where the unofficial packages are coming from. however my issue is directly stemming from 'libwxgtk3.0-dev'.  I do not know anything about wxwindows nor the PPAs